# not being able to do numpy operations on values on a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

`total_minutes_by_account` is a dictionary with values by account.

`total_min` shows the values seperated by comma  but get the error below.

```
total_min=total_minutes_by_account.values()
import numpy as np
np.mean(total_min)

File "<ipython-input-17-7834a3d1e5e6>", line 1, in <module>
    np.mean(total_min)

  File "/Users/newtopython/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2942, in mean
    out=out, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/newtopython/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 72, in _mean
    ret = ret / rcount

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict_values' and 'int'
```

Comment: Well... yeah. `np.mean` takes arrays, or at least arraylikes. You can't give it a dict values view.

Comment: An array conversion is attempted.  It's somewhat surprising to me that `np.array(d.values())` is not the same result as `np.array(list(d.values()))` .

Answer (score 5):

In Py3, `adict.values()` returns a `dict_values` object, not a list.  `numpy` functions expect numpy arrays or lists (of lists).

```
In [1618]: dd = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]}
In [1619]: dd
Out[1619]: {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
In [1620]: dd.values()
Out[1620]: dict_values([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
In [1621]: np.mean(dd.values())
... 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict_values' and 'int'
```

convert the `dict_values` to list:

```
In [1623]: list(dd.values())
Out[1623]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
In [1624]: np.mean(list(dd.values()))
Out[1624]: 3.5
```

In Py3, `range` and `dict.keys()` require the same extra touch.

========

`np.mean` first tries to convert the input to an array, but with `values()` that isn't what we want.  It makes a single item object array containing this whole object.

```
In [1626]: np.array(dd.values())
Out[1626]: array(dict_values([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]), dtype=object)
In [1627]: _.shape
Out[1627]: ()
In [1628]: np.array(list(dd.values()))
Out[1628]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: [Python 3 `range` is actually fine](http://ideone.com/z3DL4m), since it's a sequence instead of just an iterable.