# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict_values' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

this code doesn't run as expected in Python3 when I do my data-analysing practice.

The typeerror is "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict_values' and 'int'".

How should I solve it?

```
import numpy as np
# Summarize the data about minutes spent in the classroom
total_minutes = total_minutes_by_account.values()
total_minutes = np.array(total_minutes)
print('Mean:', np.mean(total_minutes))
print('Standard deviation:', np.std(total_minutes))
print('Minimum:', np.min(total_minutes))
print('Maximum:', np.max(total_minutes))
```

Comment: In python3, `dict.values` returns a `dict_values` object, which is not a `list` or `tuple`. Try coercing that into a list. `total_minutes = list(total_minutes_by_account.values())`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hopefully this helps:

The class is written in Python 2, where `Dict.values()` returns a list, but this was updated in Python 3 to return a dictionary view, described here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views

It's a potentially helpful change because the view will update when the content of the dictionary updates, but they don't behave like a `List`, and numpy's `mean`, `std`, `min`, and `max` all take a list as their argument.

Answer (score 20):

This code was giving me some unexpected trouble when going through this lesson as well, but I got it to work by making the following changes:

```
import numpy as np

total_minutes = list(total_minutes_by_account.values())
print ('Mean:', np.mean(total_minutes))
print ('Standard Deviation:', np.std(total_minutes))
print ('Minimum:', np.min(total_minutes))
print ('Maximum:', np.max(total_minutes))
```

Answer (score 11):

```
total_minutes = total_minutes_by_account.values()
```

The variable `total_minutes` will be of type `dict_values`. 
To turn it into a list you need to wrap it in a `list` function like this:

```
total_minutes = list(total_minutes_by_account.values())
```

Answer (score 2):

A very good example is given by @hpaulj at ( [not being able to do numpy operations on values on a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369705/not-being-able-to-do-numpy-operations-on-values-on-a-dictionary) )

Find below a summary of his answer. It helped me a lot.

```
In [1618]: dd = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]}
In [1619]: dd
Out[1619]: {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
In [1620]: dd.values()
Out[1620]: dict_values([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
In [1621]: np.mean(dd.values())
... 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict_values' and 'int'
```

**Solution:** convert the dict_values to list:

```
In [1623]: list(dd.values())
Out[1623]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
In [1624]: np.mean(list(dd.values()))
Out[1624]: 3.5
```

In Py3, range and dict.keys() require the same extra touch.

========

np.mean first tries to convert the input to an array, but with values() that isn't what we want. It makes a single item object array containing this whole object.

```
In [1626]: np.array(dd.values())
Out[1626]: array(dict_values([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]), dtype=object)
In [1627]: _.shape
Out[1627]: ()
In [1628]: np.array(list(dd.values()))
Out[1628]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```